# Query to return tables from mysql database not listed in a column in a table in the database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, join

I have a number of tables in my wordpress database(gooda814_bilby01).  I want a function to compare the tables in the database with the values in a column in a table in the database so that the function will then create any table not on the list.  I have a php solution that is inelegant:

```
$fdc_tables = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT distinct `fdc_form` FROM `fdc_tables`', ARRAY_A);
$wp_tables =  $wpdb->get_results('show tables from gooda814_bilby01', ARRAY_A);
foreach( $fdc_tables as $fkey => $fvalue ) { $fdc[$fkey] = $fvalue['fdc_form']; }
foreach( $wp_tables as $wkey => $wvalue ) { $wpt[$wkey] = $wvalue['Tables_in_gooda814_bilby01']; }

$required tables = (array_values((array_diff($fdc, $wpt))));
```

but I thought there might be a neat mysql join like:

```
select distinct fdc_forms from 
join show tables on Tables_in_gooda814_bilby01 = fdc_tables.fdc_forms
```

However, this of course returns an error #1064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Sub-Query instead of a `JOIN`.

**Try this SQL**

```
SELECT fdc_form 
FROM fdc_tables 
WHERE fdc_form NOT IN (
    SELECT T.TABLE_NAME
    FROM information_schema.TABLES T 
    WHERE T.TABLE_SCHEMA='gooda814_bilby01'
);
```